# xsl - turning children into parents and

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to .xsl/xslt(1.0) and have a pickle that I think I'm trying to tackle the wrong way.  I need the .xsl to be as flexible as possible in regards to actual values used, but able to evaluate data to create the report I need.

I need to create a .xsl file to tame a wild beastie of a .xml output.  It starts me with attribute strings:

```
<Journal>
   <StartTest timestamp="12:00:00" pass="1" group="A" device="a" test="stretch" />
   <EndTest timestamp="12:00:00" pass="1" group="A" device="a" test="stretch" result="Failed" />
</Journal>
```

I can get these into elements easily enough, but it is organized backwards, with my second youngest generation as the Parent to it's ancestors.
now I need to get this beastie representing just one point of data (pass/fail of a test with start and end times) while pooling all of my data into one organized chain.(ie, many tests, on multiple devices, each test grouped by a broader type, then which iteration of testing)

```
<Log>
   <Pass>1
      <Group>A
         <Device>a
            <Test>Stretch
               <StartTest>
                  <timestamp>12:00:00</timestamp>
               </StartTest>
               <EndTest>
                  <timestamp>12:00:00</timestamp>
               </EndTest>
               <Result>Fail</Result>
            </Test>
         </Device>
      </Group>
   </Pass>
</Log>
```

I'm nearing my wits end, and I need to automate this output as it is data from 100 tests(currently 200 data points) that needs to be arraigned and cataloged.  As I said I may be over complicating matters, but I need the output to be understandable to a layperson who wants something that has as little redundancy as possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem of turning that particular input into that particular output, using XSLT, is trivial. But all your talk of parents and ancestors and generations and chains makes me think that perhaps the real problem is much more complicated than your example. I don't think it's worth showing the XSLT code for your example when I clearly haven't understood most of your problem description.

Comment: Can you perhaps edit your question to show an input sample with a few more "tests" and the relevant output you expect from it? Will each `StartTest` and `EndTest` have the same number of attributes (apart from `result`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for a challenge, I am going to take a wild guess and assume you to group first by `pass`. Then for each distinct `pass` you want to group by `group` within that. Then, within the distinct `pass` and `group` you then want to group by `device`.

In XSLT 1.0, grouping is usually best achieved by a technique called [Muenchian Grouping.](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). As you have three levels of grouping, you need three keys:

```
    <xsl:key name="pass" match="StartTest" use="@pass" />
    <xsl:key name="passGroup" match="StartTest" use="concat(@pass, '-', @group)" />
    <xsl:key name="passGroupDevice" match="StartTest" use="concat(@pass, '-', @group, '-', @device)" />
```

As an example, you would get the distinct pass values, like so:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="StartTest[generate-id() = generate-id(key('pass', @pass)[1])]" mode="pass" />
```

I am going to assuming for a given combination of Pass, Group and Device you can't have more than one test with the same name. I am also going to assume for each `StartTest` there will be a corresponding `EndTest` that follows it.

With all these assumptions, this gives the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="pass" match="StartTest" use="@pass" />
    <xsl:key name="passGroup" match="StartTest" use="concat(@pass, '-', @group)" />
    <xsl:key name="passGroupDevice" match="StartTest" use="concat(@pass, '-', @group, '-', @device)" />

    <xsl:template match="Journal">
        <Log>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="StartTest[generate-id() = generate-id(key('pass', @pass)[1])]" mode="pass" />
        </Log>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StartTest" mode="pass">
        <Pass name="{@pass}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('pass', @pass)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('passGroup', concat(@pass, '-', @group))[1])]" mode="passGroup" />
        </Pass>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StartTest" mode="passGroup">
        <Group name="{@group}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('passGroup', concat(@pass, '-', @group))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('passGroupDevice', concat(@pass, '-', @group, '-', @device))[1])]" mode="passGroupDevice" />
        </Group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StartTest" mode="passGroupDevice">
        <Device name="{@device}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('passGroupDevice', concat(@pass, '-', @group, '-', @device))"/>
        </Device>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="StartTest">
        <Test name="{@test}">
            <StartTest>
                <timestamp><xsl:value-of select="@timestamp" /></timestamp>
            </StartTest>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::EndTest[1]" />
        </Test>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="EndTest">
        <EndTest>
            <timestamp><xsl:value-of select="@timestamp" /></timestamp>
        </EndTest>
        <Result>
            <xsl:value-of select="@result" />
        </Result>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, I have used attributes to record the various pass, group and device names, rather than text nodes, just to avoid hassles with indentation (To get your absolute desired results, you would have to add the new lines and spaces for the output in the XSLT, rather than use automatic indenting like the XSLT above does).

Comment: All of your above assumptions are correct. I was using elements as opposed to attributes because this is stage one, stage two involves output to a formatted report with the results for each test listed with a duration grouped in the aforementioned chains